# javascript detect if user left the site or just refreshed/clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I am using a nodejs server to display online users, but it activates the disconnected function even when the user clicks a link or refreshes the page, I am trying to bypass this, by sending a message to the server only if the user closes the tab/window with the following code:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://example.com:8000');

socket.emit('started', { username: "TestUser", });

var clicked = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[href]").click(function() {
        clicked = true;
    });

    $(document).bind('keypress keydown keyup', function(e) {
        if(e.which === 116) {
            clicked = true;
        }
        if(e.which === 82 && e.ctrlKey) {
            clicked = true;
        }
    });
});

window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    if(!clicked) {
        socket.emit('userDisconnected', { user: "TestUser" });
    }
};
```

this works for if a user clicked a link and also when a user presses F5, but how can I detect if they clicked the browsers refresh button

I basically want the userDisconnected message to be sent ONLY when the user leaves my website

thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible to detect reliably.

Comment: damn, that's a shame, thanks anyway

Comment: the closest you can get is by using cookies, to know if the user remains active or not!

Answer (score 2):

Not possible, and if it were it would probably be considered a bug. But what you did here is clever, looking for key events.

Depending on what you actually want to accomplish, you can approach it another way. Send a notification through your socket on every window unload. Put that socket on standby by setting a timeout event on that socket. Have your page also emit a reconnect signal on refresh or navigation within your site (something saying I'm back). If a socket on standby does not receive this signal within 5 (or some other number) seconds, close the connection on the server. If it does, cancel the timeout.

Comment: I second this. After a deconnection, if the user didn't reconnect within X seconds, consider it as left.